# Can't connect my android studio with MySQL database, the online server

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

guys. I am a very new beginner for android studio. I follow the Tonikami tutorial for *login and register Android Studio*. However, it doesn't work. When I register a new account, my database doesn't update, and consequently I can't login with that username and password. Someone said that it is because the android studio didn't connect to the web server. I think that might be the problem since even though I add the permission to the internet in my AndroidManifest.xml file, when I follow other tutorial, I can't open an url using my app, but I can open the website on my emulator. I don't why...

LogCat:

```
03-27 18:56:54.242 2501-2516/com.tonikamitv.pilldispenser W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "shiyulian.comxa.comRegister.php": No address associated with hostname
03-27 18:56:54.242 2501-2516/com.tonikamitv.pilldispenser W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:470)
03-27 18:56:54.242 2501-2516/com.tonikamitv.pilldispenser W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
03-27 18:56:54.242 2501-2516/com.tonikamitv.pilldispenser W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
03-27 18:56:54.242 2501-2516/com.tonikamitv.pilldispenser W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
03-27 18:56:54.242 2501-2516/com.tonikamitv.pilldispenser W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
03-27 18:56:54.242 2501-2516/com.tonikamitv.pilldispenser W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
03-27 18:56:54.242 2501-2516/com.tonikamitv.pilldispenser W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:366)
03-27 18:56:54.242 2501-2516/com.tonikamitv.pilldispenser W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
03-27 18:56:54.242 2501-2516/com.tonikamitv.pilldispenser W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
03-27 18:56:54.243 2501-2516/com.tonikamitv.pilldispenser W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:470)
03-27 18:56:54.243 2501-2516/com.tonikamitv.pilldispenser W/System.err:     at com.tonikamitv.pilldispenser.ServerRequests$StoreUserDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(ServerRequests.java:93)
03-27 18:56:54.243 2501-2516/com.tonikamitv.pilldispenser W/System.err:     at com.tonikamitv.pilldispenser.ServerRequests$StoreUserDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(ServerRequests.java:67)
03-27 18:56:54.243 2501-2516/com.tonikamitv.pilldispenser W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
03-27 18:56:54.243 2501-2516/com.tonikamitv.pilldispenser W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-27 18:56:54.243 2501-2516/com.tonikamitv.pilldispenser W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
03-27 18:56:54.243 2501-2516/com.tonikamitv.pilldispenser W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
03-27 18:56:54.243 2501-2516/com.tonikamitv.pilldispenser W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
03-27 18:56:54.243 2501-2516/com.tonikamitv.pilldispenser W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
03-27 18:56:54.244 2501-2516/com.tonikamitv.pilldispenser W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
03-27 18:56:54.244 2501-2516/com.tonikamitv.pilldispenser W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
03-27 18:56:54.244 2501-2516/com.tonikamitv.pilldispenser W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
03-27 18:56:54.244 2501-2516/com.tonikamitv.pilldispenser W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451)
03-27 18:56:54.244 2501-2516/com.tonikamitv.pilldispenser W/System.err:     ... 17 more
```

shiyulian.comxa.com is my web server domain

Here is my Register.PHP file:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $age = $_POST["age"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO User (name, age, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $age, $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

When I open this file by File Manager on the server, by the way I am using 000webhost, the same as it is in the tutorial, it shows the warning message as following:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'my_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/a6969519/public_html/Register.php on line 2
Warning: mysqli_prepare() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /home/a6969519/public_html/Register.php on line 9
Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in /home/a6969519/public_html/Register.php on line 10
Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in /home/a6969519/public_html/Register.php on line 11
Warning: mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in /home/a6969519/public_html/Register.php on line 13

Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /home/a6969519/public_html/Register.php on line 15
```

Here is the FetchUserData.php

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");


    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $name, $age, $username, $password);

    $user = array();

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        $user[name] = $name;
        $user[age] = $age;
        $user[username] = $username;
        $user[password] = $password;
    }

    echo json_encode($user);

    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);


    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Here is the warning:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'my_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/a6969519/public_html/FetchUserData.php on line 2
Warning: mysqli_prepare() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /home/a6969519/public_html/FetchUserData.php on line 8
Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in /home/a6969519/public_html/FetchUserData.php on line 9
Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in /home/a6969519/public_html/FetchUserData.php on line 10
Warning: mysqli_stmt_store_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in /home/a6969519/public_html/FetchUserData.php on line 12

Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in /home/a6969519/public_html/FetchUserData.php on line 13
Warning: mysqli_stmt_fetch() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in /home/a6969519/public_html/FetchUserData.php on line 17

Warning: mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in /home/a6969519/public_html/FetchUserData.php on line 26
Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /home/a6969519/public_html/FetchUserData.php on line 29
```

Here is code for my ServerRequests java class:

```
public class ServerRequests {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 1000 * 15;
    public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://shiyulian.comxa.com";

    public ServerRequests(Context context){
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Process");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    }

    public void storeUserDataInBackground(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback){
        progressDialog.show();
        new StoreUserDataAsyncTask(user, userCallback).execute();
    }

    public void fetchUserDataInBackground(User user, GetUserCallback callBack){

        progressDialog.show();
        new fetchUserDataAsyncTask(user, callBack).execute();
    }

        public class StoreUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

            User user;
            GetUserCallback userCallback;
            public StoreUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback){
                this.user = user;
                this.userCallback = userCallback;
            }
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
                dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", user.name));
                dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", user.age+""));
                dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
                dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));

                HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "Register.php");

                try{
                    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
                    client.execute(post);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }


            @Override
              protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

                progressDialog.dismiss();
                userCallback.done(null);

                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            }
        }

    public class fetchUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, User>{
        User user;
        GetUserCallback userCallback;

        public fetchUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback){
            this.user = user;
            this.userCallback = userCallback;
        }

        @Override
        protected User doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));

            HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "FetchUserData.php");

            User returnedUser = null;
            try{
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

                HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);

                if(jObject.length() == 0){
                    returnedUser = null;
                } else{
                    String name = jObject.getString("name");
                    int age = jObject.getInt("age");

                    returnedUser = new User(name,age, user.username, user.password );
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return returnedUser;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(User returneduser) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            userCallback.done(returneduser);
            super.onPostExecute(returneduser);
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for such a log code.
If more information is need, please let me know. Thanks so much for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

On another note, I would suggest you connect to your MySQL through pinging a server instead of directly connecting through Android. The reasons follow

1. Pinging MySQL through Android is resource consuming and compute intensive task
2. Security breach issues.

Instead, create a server like Node JS, PHP Yii, Rails, Play, etc and ping on the server which would actually interact with the database by executing the queries and bring you the results on Android.

If you still, however, want to go ahead with MySQL interaction with Android, there are some relevant tutorials on Android developers documentation on the website of Android.